# LoadRunner parameter parameter with spaces

Tags: loadrunner

I am scripting a VUser LoadRunner script and want to save a parameter that is between to boundries in this html:

```
<span id="ident" class="control-label">
My parameter
<span>
```

But the problem is that LR fails using this code:

web_reg_save_param("Some_Txt", "LB=ident" class="control-label">", "RB=",LAST );

With the errors:

Action.c (34): syntax error; found `class' expecting`)'

Action.c (34): syntax error; found `class' expecting`;'

Action.c (34): undeclared identifier `class'

Action.c (34): syntax error; found `RB' expecting`;'

Action.c (34): undeclared identifier `RB'

Action.c (34): illegal expression

Action.c (34): missing "

Action.c (34): undeclared identifier `sp'

Action.c (34): syntax error; found ",LAST ); " expecting `;'

Action.c (36): syntax error; found `web_submit_data' expecting`;'

Action.c (37): missing

I am not sure about the error msgs. What is the clue here? Is the problem spaces or "" or something else?

Cheers
Magnus

Comment: Ok, so i modified a bit with some \'s, but then the script fails with this msg:

Error: C interpreter run time error: Action.c (34):  Error -- memory violation : Exception ACCESS_VIOLATION received.

Comment: this causes the fault now i.e. ACCESS_VIOLATION:
web_reg_save_param("Some_Txt", "LB=ident\" class=\"control-label">"", "RB=</spa", LAST);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect syntax on your web_reg_Save para().   Please refer to your foundation skills in C programming on how to escape quotes inside of a string.   *Assuming* that the capture section you have presented is correct across multiple lines of HTML then you will find that you are likely missing additional characters in the left boundary condition.   You will also need a better descriptor in the right boundary condition other than a NULL condition.

This answer does not include a solution, but a path to a solution:
Research:

- Escaping quotes inside of another string in C
- Control characters at the end of lines in C representing line breaks and carriage return
  Research: Distinct Right boundary condition (not null), which may include control characters
- Ordinal/Instance of the match condition
- Location. Is the location of the web_reg_...() appropriate to the location need for the capture.

Researching the above should lead to a stronger understanding of the solution you choose to implement.

Comment: Thank you, I found that escaping quotes by using \ inside the web_reg_save para() solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

the syntax in this function ---

```
 web_reg_save_param("Some_Txt", "LB=ident" class="control-label">", "RB=",LAST );
```

is wrong. It has "," before the class like ---

```
web_reg_save_param("Some_Txt", "LB=ident",class="control-label\">", "RB= ",LAST );
```

Try this one...