# LoadRunner dynamic value

Tags: loadrunner

I have a challenge with a dynamic value that is being created in a web_url like this:

```
web_url("klargjore", 

            "URL=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/klargjore?3-1.IBehaviorListener.0-neste&_=1357544083160", 

            "TargetFrame=",
```

The errormessage says:

Action.c(37): Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/klargjore?3-1.IBehaviorListener.0-neste&_=1357544083160"       [MsgId: MERR-26612]

The problem is that it is not possible to use correlation for this value because it is created when the url is built, at leat so it seems. I cannot capture it in any way from the server and reuse it in the url as one would do in manuel correlation.
Maybe I am missing something here, but is there a way to check if 1357544083160 is sent form the server?

```
Action()

{



    web_url("vedtak", 

            "URL=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/", 

            "TargetFrame=", 

            "Resource=0", 

            "RecContentType=text/html", 

            "Referer=", 

            "Snapshot=t1.inf", 

            "Mode=HTML", 

            EXTRARES, 

            "Url=statisk/css/images/navlogo.jpg", "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=lYqFC7YlETkjBwcS+iVN7a+6?0", ENDITEM, 

            "Url=statisk/css/images/prosessteg_klargjore.png", "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=lYqFC7YlETkjBwcS+iVN7a+6?0", ENDITEM, 

            "Url=statisk/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png", "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=lYqFC7YlETkjBwcS+iVN7a+6?0", ENDITEM, 

            LAST);



    web_submit_data("opprett;jsessionid=lYqFC7YlETkjBwcS+iVN7a+6", 

            "Action=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=lYqFC7YlETkjBwcS+iVN7a+6?0-1.IFormSubmitListener-oppretteBehandlingForm", 

            "Method=POST", 

            "TargetFrame=", 

            "RecContentType=text/html", 

            "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=lYqFC7YlETkjBwcS+iVN7a+6?0", 

            "Snapshot=t2.inf", 

            "Mode=HTML", 

            ITEMDATA, 

            "Name=neste", "Value=x", ENDITEM, 

            "Name=fnr", "Value=10014549957", ENDITEM, 

            "Name=mottattDato", "Value=07.01.2013", ENDITEM, 

            EXTRARES, 

            "Url=../wicket/resource/no.nav.vedtak.web.pages.base.BasePage/jquery.placeholder-ver-1356010900000.js", "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/klargjore?3", ENDITEM, 

            "Url=../statisk/img/glyphicons-halflings.png", "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/klargjore?3", ENDITEM, 

            LAST);



    lr_think_time(7);



    web_url("klargjore", 

            "URL=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/klargjore?3-1.IBehaviorListener.0-neste&_=1357544083160", 

            "TargetFrame=", 

            "Resource=0", 

            "RecContentType=text/xml", 

            "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/klargjore?3", 

            "Snapshot=t3.inf", 

            "Mode=HTML", 

            LAST);



    web_url("vurderevilkar", 

            "URL=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/vurderevilkar", 

            "TargetFrame=", 

            "Resource=0", 

            "RecContentType=text/html", 

            "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/klargjore?3", 

            "Snapshot=t4.inf", 

            "Mode=HTML", 

            EXTRARES, 

            "Url=/vedtak/statisk/css/images/Prosessteg_vurdere_vilkar.png", "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/vurderevilkar?5", ENDITEM, 

            "Url=/vedtak/statisk/css/images/icon_ok.png", "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/vurderevilkar?5", ENDITEM, 

            "Url=/vedtak/statisk/css/images/icon_ikke_ok.png", "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/vurderevilkar?5", ENDITEM, 

            LAST);



    return 0;

}
```

Virtual User Script started at : 2013-01-07 08:35:07

Starting action vuser_init.

Web Turbo Replay of LoadRunner 11.0.0 for Windows 7; build 9375 (May 18 2011 01:44:32)   [MsgId: MMSG-27143]

Run Mode: HTML   [MsgId: MMSG-26000]

Run-Time Settings file: "C:\Users\F119506\AppData\Local\Temp\noname20\default.cfg"      [MsgId: MMSG-27141]

Ending action vuser_init.

Running Vuser...

Starting iteration 1.

Starting action Action.

Action.c(4): Redirecting "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/" (redirection depth is 0)          [MsgId: MMSG-26694]

Action.c(4): To location "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett"         [MsgId: MMSG-26693]

Action.c(4): Redirecting "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett" (redirection depth is 1)        [MsgId: MMSG-26694]

Action.c(4): To location "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"   [MsgId: MMSG-26693]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/modig-ver-1352360328000.css" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"   [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/BasePage-ver-1356010900000.css" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"        [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/datepicker-ver-1356010900000.css" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"      [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/KlargjoreForVedtakPage-ver-1356010900000.css" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"          [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/VurdereVilkarPage-ver-1356010900000.css" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"       [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"       [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"    [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"         [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-button-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"        [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"      [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"      [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"      [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"         [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"       [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"       [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"     [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"   [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"     [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix-ver-1352360328000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"         [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap-datepicker-ver-1356010900000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"      [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/KlargjoreForVedtakPage-ver-1356010900000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"    [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.DebugBar/wicket-debugbar-ver-1350674618000.css" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"        [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.DebugBar/wicket-debugbar-ver-1350674618000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"         [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.DebugBar/wicket-ver-1350674618000.png" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"         [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.inspector.InspectorPage/bug-ver-1350674618000.png" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"      [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.SessionSizeDebugPanel/harddrive-ver-1350674618000.png" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"         [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.DebugBar/remove-ver-1350674618000.png" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=abH1X9LF+cnPumVk3-+8A4Ys?0"         [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(4): Downloading resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/images/navlogo.jpg" (specified by argument number 10)          [MsgId: MMSG-26577]

Action.c(4): Downloading resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/images/prosessteg_klargjore.png" (specified by argument number 13)     [MsgId: MMSG-26577]

Action.c(4): Downloading resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png" (specified by argument number 16)      [MsgId: MMSG-26577]

Action.c(4): web_url("vedtak") was successful, 526330 body bytes, 9391 header bytes, 13 chunking overhead bytes          [MsgId: MMSG-26385]

Action.c(18): Redirecting "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/opprett;jsessionid=lYqFC7YlETkjBwcS+iVN7a+6?0-1.IFormSubmitListener-oppretteBehandlingForm" (redirection depth is 0)    [MsgId: MMSG-26694]

Action.c(18): To location "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23829/klargjore"        [MsgId: MMSG-26693]

Action.c(18): Redirecting "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23829/klargjore" (redirection depth is 1)       [MsgId: MMSG-26694]

Action.c(18): To location "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23829/klargjore?2"      [MsgId: MMSG-26693]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/modig-ver-1352360328000.css" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again     [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/BasePage-ver-1356010900000.css" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again          [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/datepicker-ver-1356010900000.css" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again        [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/KlargjoreForVedtakPage-ver-1356010900000.css" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again    [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/css/VurdereVilkarPage-ver-1356010900000.css" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again         [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again         [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again      [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again   [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-button-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again          [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again        [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again        [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again        [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again   [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again         [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again         [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again       [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again     [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again       [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix-ver-1352360328000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again   [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/bootstrap-datepicker-ver-1356010900000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again        [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/js/KlargjoreForVedtakPage-ver-1356010900000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again      [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.DebugBar/wicket-debugbar-ver-1350674618000.css" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again          [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.DebugBar/wicket-debugbar-ver-1350674618000.js" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again   [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior/res/js/wicket-event-jquery-ver-1350674288000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23829/klargjore?2"   [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(18): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior/res/js/wicket-ajax-jquery-ver-1350674288000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23829/klargjore?2"    [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(18): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior/res/js/wicket-ajax-jquery-debug-ver-1350674288000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23829/klargjore?2"      [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(18): Found resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/no.nav.vedtak.web.pages.base.BasePage/jquery.placeholder-ver-1356010900000.js" in HTML "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23829/klargjore?2"        [MsgId: MMSG-26659]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.DebugBar/wicket-ver-1350674618000.png" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again   [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.inspector.InspectorPage/bug-ver-1350674618000.png" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again        [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.SessionSizeDebugPanel/harddrive-ver-1350674618000.png" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again   [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.DebugBar/remove-ver-1350674618000.png" is in the cache already and will not be downloaded again   [MsgId: MMSG-26655]

Action.c(18): Downloading resource "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/statisk/img/glyphicons-halflings.png" (specified by argument number 23)   [MsgId: MMSG-26577]

Action.c(18): web_submit_data("opprett;jsessionid=lYqFC7YlETkjBwcS+iVN7a+6") was successful, 116948 body bytes, 2268 header bytes, 20 chunking overhead bytes    [MsgId: MMSG-26385]

Action.c(37): Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/23821/klargjore?3-1.IBehaviorListener.0-neste&_=1357544083160"       [MsgId: MERR-26612]

Action.c(37): web_url("klargjore") highest severity level was "ERROR", 4930 body bytes, 242 header bytes, 13 chunking overhead bytes     [MsgId: MMSG-26387]

Ending action Action.

Ending iteration 1.

Ending Vuser...

Starting action vuser_end.

Ending action vuser_end.

Vuser Terminated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnus, may I suggest you spend some time with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [HTTP Watch](http://www.httpwatch.com/), or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what the application is actually doing first. Even better, try the "View Source" option in your browser, you might be surprised at what you find.

You can not automate something if you don't know what happens when you do it manually.

Your script has no verification, and it really seems like you don't understand how the application works. You perform a data submit then do a web_url straight afterwards. Is this simulating the user clicking a link? If so, then the link must exist in the page right? Try web_reg_save_param / web_reg_save_param_ex and extract the address that way.

Don't just blindly write a script that pumps HTTP requests at the server without verification or understanding what the app is doing.

A unique tag at the end of a URL is most likely a caching mechanism rather than a dodgy unique identifier. This way, the HTTP header is set to never expire, and the item will be cached until the application is updated with a new unique identifier. Either way, its highly unlikely that there is application verification of this value that would cause a 500 error when incorrect.

Also Magnus, if you get an answer to your problem, press accept. 12 questions and no accept, even though there has been successful answers on your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626428/loadrunner-parameter-parameter-with-spaces).

Comment: Joal, 
I do know what the application is doing and my script contains a lot of valdiations with i.e. text I expect to find "on the next" page is present and so forth. 
But the issue I raised in this post did not concern general LR good scripting practices, but rather a concrete question that is now solved.
 
I will go through my pstst and accept the answers. Sorry about that.

Thank you!
Kind Regards Magnus

Comment: Hi Magnus,
I am glad that you got your answer sorted. The reason I mentioned this, is that in your script you also have another timestamp used to manage caching. `../wicket/resource/no.nav.vedtak.web.pages.base.BasePage/jquery.placeholder-ver-1356010900000.js`.

Comment: [CONTINUED] There is no way that a URL is created when the url is built, at least so it seems. This value will be handled either in the application itself and embedded in the <a href> tag, or generated on the client side via JavaScript. My apologies if this came off as being preachy.

Comment: If it is created on the clientside using i.e. JS. How can I capture it then?

Comment: Unfortunately, the best way is to analyse the Javascript and figure out how its calculating this ID. As mentioned above, its probably timestamp related. Annoyingly when this happens, the best way is to figure out how its done in JS and recode it in C.

Answer (score 2):

Your 13 digit number is a unix timestamp/time since epoch, most likely generated locally (instead of coming from the server) by some enterprising developer looking for a quasi-unique number to uniquely identify the request to the server.

```
      1357544083160 = Mon, 7 Jan 2013 07:34:43.160 UTC
```

This is most likely the time that you recorded the business conversation which is the basis for your web virtual user code.

Examine the helpfile for **web_save_timestamp_param()** for something which would be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

If that is timestamp then you need to write function to get current time stamp. I would think the error would be due to wicket(3-1) error. You need to correlate dynamic url 3-1.IBehaviorListener